# pandas.to_datetime return NaT starting from 2270-12-31

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I am using python 3.5.3 with pandas 0.21.0

The following date in the future is working:

```
pandas.to_datetime('2260-12-31', format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
Timestamp('2260-12-31 00:00:00')
```

but for starting fron 2270 it is not accepted anymore:

```
pandas.to_datetime('2270-12-31', format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
NaT
```

If I use datetime.strptime it works in all cases:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2270-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2270, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```

or

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('9999-12-31-23.59.59.999999', '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

Is it because pandas return a Timestamp and the second one a datetime.datetime ?

In the pandas documentation I see the following but I don't know what is the value for Timestamp.max. With other option it in the best case return the initial string.

> In case when it is not possible to return designated types (e.g. when
>   any element of input is before Timestamp.min or after Timestamp.max)
>   return will have datetime.datetime type (or correspoding
>   array/Series).

Is there a way to have it working with to_datetime ? It is very convenient when you have many columns all with different date and timestamp pattern and when you want to transform all of them from object to datetime64[ns] in your pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as intended. The reason for this is that timestamps are actually integers under the hood. They represent a 64 bit integer + an offset time. In this case '2270-12-31' is too far from the offset to fit inside a 64 bit integer so it says not a time.

Comment: yes, I was too fast. Here the maximum value Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807'):  [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.max.html)